# Python - split strings inside array

Tags: python

I have an array that looks something like this:

```
arr1 = ["1", "2", "3 4", "5 6 7", "8"]
```

and I want to, somehow, split the strings with spaces in them turning this array into this:

```
split_arr1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"]
```

Note: The split array does not have to be in order

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Iterating the input list and using `split`:

```
arr1 = ["1", "2", "3 4", "5 6 7", "8"]
output = []
for item in arr1:
    output.extend(item.split())

print(output)  # ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
```

For each entry in the input list we call `extend` on some output list (initially empty).  This will add each element from splitting e.g. `"5 6 7"` as a new separate entry in the output list.

Comment: @wl2776 [That won't work](https://rextester.com/BJYUJ74454), because a list comprehension is using `append` under the hood, while we need `extend` here (hence my explicit loop).  Though I would prefer to also use a list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using nested list comprehension:

```py
arr1 = ["1", "2", "3 4", "5 6 7", "8"]

split_arr1 = [split_item for item in arr1 for split_item in item.split()]
# ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution:

```
arr1 = ["1", "2", "3 4", "5 6 7", "8"]

split_arr1 = list("".join(arr1).replace(" ", ""))
```

Explanation:

1. Join all strings into one string -> `"123 45 6 78"`
2. Remove any white spaces -> `"12345678"`
3. Split each character -> `['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']`

Comment: What if original array would have strings longer than one character?

Comment: well, i am assuming that its single digits as per his example.